# R: diff() and tsibble - must be size n or 1 not n-2

Tags: r, tidyverse, tsibble

Given:

```
test <- tsibble(
  date = lubridate::now() + 0:9,
  value = rnorm(10)
)  %>%
  mutate (vdiff =diff(value, differences = 2))
```

How do I avoid the following :

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `vdiff`. ℹ `vdiff = diff(value, differences = 2, na.pad = TRUE)`. ℹ `vdiff` must be size 10 or 1, not
> 8

I tried adding `na.pad = TRUE` but that has no effect (and in any event,  I would prefer to pad with `0` not `NA`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach to achieve your desired result would be to make use of `dplyr::lag`. However thanks to the comment by @MitchellO'Hara-Wild there is an easier way to achieve this by simply making use of `tsibble::difference`

```r
library(tsibble)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(42)

d <- tsibble(
  date = lubridate::now() + 0:9,
  value = rnorm(10)
)  
#> Using `date` as index variable.

d %>%
  mutate(vdiff = difference(value, differences = 2, default = 0))
#> # A tsibble: 10 x 3 [1s] <?>
#>    date                  value  vdiff
#>    <dttm>                <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1 2021-06-20 14:33:28  1.37    0    
#>  2 2021-06-20 14:33:29 -0.565   0    
#>  3 2021-06-20 14:33:30  0.363   2.86 
#>  4 2021-06-20 14:33:31  0.633  -0.658
#>  5 2021-06-20 14:33:32  0.404  -0.498
#>  6 2021-06-20 14:33:33 -0.106  -0.282
#>  7 2021-06-20 14:33:34  1.51    2.13 
#>  8 2021-06-20 14:33:35 -0.0947 -3.22 
#>  9 2021-06-20 14:33:36  2.02    3.72 
#> 10 2021-06-20 14:33:37 -0.0627 -4.19
```

Comment: You could also use the `difference()` function which pads the values with NA.

Comment: @MitchellO'Hara-Wild. Thanks for pointing that out. Wasn't aware of that a I'm not familiar with the `tsibble` package. Even more problematic, my approach actually results in the wrong result as I missed the difference between "lag" and "differences".